# How would you solve this resistive network?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, voltage-measurement, network, ohms

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP5zNm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm not really sure how to solve this. I can't see any series or parallel connections.

I need to find the Total resistance, V1 and V2, and finally I3 with a direction.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

(edit)

[image: re-drawn after taking suggestions]

Okay so now I have taken your suggestions and redrawn it and worked out the values. 
it is much easier now to work out, so thanks for all the great suggestions.

Feel free to correct me on any faults in my calculations.

Comment: What is V1 and V2? Also I3? I would use Thevenin equivalent circuits to solve for V1/2 then use those to get I3 if it's related.

Comment: Redraw/rearrange the schematic.  Keep redrawing until you *see* it.  The schematic is simpler than it looks.

Comment: @brhans  I'm deleting your comment, because we don't do *simply* solve homeworks for the interwebs on EE.SE.

Comment: Lol... I actually just glanced at it and didn't realize. Brilliantly done on the profs part. Not so brilliant on the students.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this I relabeled it.

Comment: Another way to see this is to label the nodes in your circuit. You should have done that anyway to make it easier for us to talk about the circuit with you.

Comment: And I've tried redrawing but the horizontal wires are confusing me.

Comment: Okay I'll label the nodes too.

Comment: Mark every node in a different color, this might help you see it.

Comment: @Omuse: Nicely done. :) What's the value of Is?

Comment: @EM Fields Thanks, couldn't have done it without your help.

Comment: oh yeah it's Is=Vs/Rt = 32/2.75 = 11.64 A?

Comment: You're welcome; my pleasure :). 11.64A? Right you are!

Comment: Yay cool. xD Now the circuit looks so easy. ha

Answer (score 3):

This is a really easy circuit to solve.  The reason it appears difficult is because the schematic is obfuscated by deliberately using unintuitive layout.  First, this is a good lesson on why logical schematic layout matters.  Second, you'll see this circuit is actually very simply once you draw it logically.

In general, draw schematics with power and ground voltages being horizontal lines sorted by ascending voltage bottom to top.  Then show the rest of the circuit with logical flow (nothing to do with current flow) left to right.

In your case, draw the battery at left with the positive node going up from the top, then across the sheet to the right.  Similarly, the negative node should go down from the battery, then across the sheet left to right.  Now fill in the resistors vertically between the two horizontal power lines that run across the top and bottom of the sheet.

Once you do this, the circuit will be obvious and you'll wonder how you didn't see it before.

Hint: Look at how many nodes this circuit actually has.  Yes, it really is that simple.

Comment: Oh I just noticed now everything is in parallel

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a homework question.  Please do us all a favor next time and actually tell us that right up front.  We won't GIVE you the answer but we'll help you figure it out yourself.

I'll start off by making a suggestion.  Follow the line from the battery (+) terminal and mark each end of every resistor that connects to that (+) terminal.  Use the letter A to keep it simple.

Now do the same for the battery (-) and use the letter B.

Now re-draw the schematic with that information.

Modify your question if you are still having problems.

[Edit]

I'll add one more suggestion: re-draw the schematic with the battery on the left and all of the resistors on the right.  Place all of the resistors vertically with all of the same letter at the top.

Comment: That was my main intention to learn how to work this out. Answers mean nothing without the working out.

Comment: Then you aren't trying.  I'm *NOT* going to give you any more information until you post a re-drawn schematic based on my suggestion.

Comment: Maybe I should have replied when I finished drawing the circuit not in the middle of it. whoops...

Comment: Well it's done now. I also re-edited it with a new comment.

Comment: Oh wait damn I redrawn it under someone else's advise...

Comment: Sorry about that. I redrew it using your suggestion now.

Answer (score 0):

As Olin said - Yes its really that simple.

[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't just give out the answer to a homework question like this.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: What the OP stated was: "I need to find the Total resistance, V1 and V2, and finally I3 with a direction." So where did Jim Dearden spill the beans?

Comment: Yeah I drew it before So now answers were given out.

Answer (score 0):

If you pretty up your circuit it'll look something like the schematic below, so now all that's left is to figure out - knowing that V1 and V2 are merely the the battery voltage across the array - is I3, then the resistance of all the resistors in parallel and, finally, Is.

[image]

Comment: You really should let the OP do the work of a homework question like this. By the way, you got I3 wrong. Also, we've been trying to teach a consistant way of drawing schematics with power busses horizontal sorted by descending voltage top to bottom. While your schematic is correct, I would really like it to be rotated 90 deg right to reinforce what we are trying to teach instead of undermining it.

Comment: My schematic is perfectly legible and understandable, and I'm really not concerned with what you like or what you consider to be proper drawing procedure/aesthetics since I edited a real dog you once posted and you rolled it back to its original ugliness purely for egotistical reasons.  As far as the homework thing goes, you really should look at posting times before you start coming to unwarranted conclusions. As for \$ I_{3} \$, conventional current is considered to exit a source and enter a load, so you must be thinking of something else.  What might that be, pray tell?

Comment: @Olin Lathrop Don't worry about, it I found out already that everything is in parallel. I understand why you preferred it drawn your way. It is easier to guess the direction of flow of current.

Comment: @EM Fields I also think I3 is across R3 like in the original schematic. If not anyone feel free to correct me.

Comment: @Omuse: Physically, charge flows _through_ a resistor while voltage appears _across_ it, so I3, being a current, would go through R3 instead of appearing across it.

Comment: @EM Fields ohh so is that the reason voltage is measured in parallel with a DMM. While resistance is measured in series?

Comment: @Omuse: Yes, but it's current that's measured with the DMM as a series element of the circuit.  Resistance is a whole nother ball of wax and deserves its own question.

Comment: Oh okay, I should look into that later.

Comment: I3 is still wrong. Note it's polarity in the original schematic as opposed to yours.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I guess it's impossible for the original schematic to have an error in it, huh?

Comment: Since the original schematic is the definition of the problem, technically it can't be wrong. In this case, given all the other deliberate obfuscation, I expect the professor deliberately arranged R3 so that current thru it would flow right to left and has a -1 waiting for anyone that fails to realize I3 is negative.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Utter nonsense Olin, you're grasping at straws.  Since resistors are polarity-blind, if the professor either deliberately or accidentally mislabeled I3's direction, it's still wrong and he most likely would have given me a +1 for detecting the error.  Some errors of your own: "I expect" should read: "I suspect", and where did I2 come from?